# Best strategy to develop back end of an app with large userbase, taking into account limitations of bandwidth, concurrent connections etc.?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, cloud, hosting, backend

I am developing an Android app which basically does this: On the landing(home) page it shows a couple of words. These words need to be updated on daily basis. Secondly, there is an 'experiences' tab in which a list of user experiences (around 500) shows up with their profile pic, description,etc.

This basic app is expected to get around 1 million users daily who will open the app daily at least once to see those couple of words. Many may occasionally open up the experiences section.

Thirdly, the app needs to have a push notification feature.

I am planning to purchase a managed wordpress hosting, set up a website, and add a post each day with those couple of words, use the JSON-API to extract those words and display them on app's home page. Similarly for the experiences, I will add each as a wordpress post and extract them from the Wordpress database. The reason I am choosing wordpress is that it has ready made interfaces for data entry which will save my time and effort.

But I am stuck on this: will the wordpress DB be able to handle such large amount of queries ? With such a large userbase and spiky traffic, I suspect I might cross the max. concurrent connections limit.

What's the best strategy in my case ? Should I use WP, or use firebase or any other service ? I need to make sure the scheme is cost effective also.
My app is basically very similar to this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ekaum.ekaum

For push notifications, I am planning to use third party services.
Kindly suggest the best strategy I should go with for designing the back end of this app.
Thanks to everyone out there in advance who are willing to help me in this.

Comment: Why would your traffic be spiky? You mean when you send notifications? You don't need to send them to ALL your users at once, you can send them gradually.

Comment: Because most of the people would open the app once at around 9-10 am and then in the evening at around 5-6 pm. I have tested this that's why I know that the traffic would be spiky. Can you give any suggestions on how to design the back end for my case ?

Comment: I just downloaded the Ekaum app. The experiences seem to be quite static. You can send your experience via email, so I guess there's an admin that reviews them and adds them to the app. How are you going to update the experiences in your app?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Wordpress, so I don't know if or how it could handle that load.

You can still use WP for data entry, and [write a scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) that would use WP's JSON API to copy that data into Firebase.

[RTDB-vs-Firestore scalability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore#scalability) states that RTDB can handle 200 thousand concurrent connections and Firestore 1 million concurrent connections.

However, if I get it right, your app doesn't need connections to be active (i.e. receive real-time updates). You can get your data once, then close the connection.

For RTDB, [Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) states that

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the [goOffline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()) method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

So the connection should close by itself after 1 minute, if you remove your listeners, or you can force close it earlier using [goOffline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()).

For Firestore, I don't know if it happens automatically, but [you can do it manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access).

In [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) you can see that 100K Firestore document reads is $0.06. 1M reads (for the two words) should cost $0.6 plus some network traffic. In RTDB, the cost has to do with data bulk, so it requires some calculations, but it shouldn't be much. I am not familiar with the pricing small details, so you should do some more research.

In the app you mentioned, the experiences don't seem to change very often. You might want to try to build your own caching manually, and add the required versioning info in the daily data.

---

Edit:

It would possibly be more efficient and less costly if you used Firebase Hosting, instead of RTDB/Firestore directly. See [Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) and [Manage cache behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache).

In short, you create a [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request) that reads your database and returns the data you need. You configure hosting to call that function, and configure the cache such that subsequent requests are served the cached result via hosting (without extra function invocations).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208765/discussion-on-answer-by-stratubas-best-strategy-to-develop-back-end-of-an-app-wi).